# Laptop with MX Linux cannot `xrandr --addmode` 1366x768 after installing NVIDIA driver

Tags: display, xrandr, resolution, display-settings

### What I have

An old ASUS P43S laptop. NVIDIA GeForce GT520M video card. HDD. Very outdated. Emerson 32" LCD TV (no model number in the front, software TVNB2064_08_UH_XX91_GB0) connected to its HDMI output. Dual boot: Windows 7 and MX Linux.

### What I want to achieve

1. MX Linux.
2. Mirror display: LCD TV (HDMI) and laptop builtin display.
3. 1366x768 resolution on both displays. If cannot achieve, acceptable if both are at the same 1360x768 or 1280x768 resolution.
4. Audio through HDMI.
5. No software defect like missing GUI components.

### What I tried

#### Windows 7

**Summary: Works perfectly as expected.**

This used to be a pretty common issue. My old laptop's builtin display is 1366x768, and I connect a LCD TV to it on its HDMI port. I want the TV to mirror the laptop display, i.e., both should show 1366x768 pictures. This works perfectly fine in my Windows 7.

PS: My TV is an Emerson 32". Its LCD looks best at 1366x768 but if I connect it to any computer, the computer seems to believe that the TV is best at 1920x1080, but actually if I set it to 1920x1080 I can see text blurs due to scaling. Therefore, I personally believe my TV's optimal resolution is 1366x768 instead of 1920x1080. Even if it is not the case, I still want it to display at 1366x768 because it looks the best to me at this resolution and it works in Windows 7.

[image: Windows display settings]

**Update:** I notice that when I select 1366x768 in Windows 7, if I use the TV remote to show the input info, it says "1080p HD 60Hz".

#### MX Linux and opensource video driver

**Summary: LCD TV says resolution mismatch but still works correctly. NO HDMI audio.**

After switching to MX Linux, at beginning, it was using the default opensource video driver. In display settings, the TV only has 1360x768 resolution, as well as others like 1920x1080, 1280x768, etc., but not 1366x768. I was able to use `xrandr --addmode` to add the 1366x768 mode that my laptop display is using to the HDMI-1 display as follows

```
xrandr --addmode HDMI-1 "1366x768"
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --mode "1366x768"
```

Note that "xrandr --newmode" was not necessary because the mode was already being used by the laptop display. These commands worked mostly okay, except that when I set the mode, my TV gave a "resolution mismatch" warning popup, but it displayed the picture correctly.

However, audio did not work with HDMI output -- I could not select HDMI as audio output. After some brief research, I decided that I needed to install the NVIDIA driver for my laptop (video card: GeForce GT520M).

#### MX Linux with NVIDIA driver

**Summary: LCD TV cannot add custom resolution, stuck at 1360x768 and taskbar disappears if I set LCD TV as primary display.**

Now HDMI audio works.

However, in `xrandr` output, "HDMI-1" became "HDMI-0", no big deal. The problem now is that it still does not have 1366x768 as a mode and now I can no longer add 1366x768 to its mode list using the above commands that used to work before. If I run that `xrandr --addmode HDMI-0 "1366x768"` now, it says "X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)".

`xrandr` now gives as follows:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1366 x 768, maximum 16384 x 16384
VGA-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
LVDS-0 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 174mm
   1366x768      60.00*+
HDMI-0 connected 1360x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1920x1080     60.00 +  59.94    30.00    29.97    24.00    23.98    60.00
   1360x768      60.02*
   1280x768      59.99
   1280x720      60.00    59.94
   1024x768      60.00
   800x600       60.32
   720x480       59.94
   640x480       59.94    59.93
```

I read something somewhere (sorry forgot where it was) and that person says they changed some values in their `xorg.conf` and then it worked for them. However, I do not have `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` and I don't know where it is. Even if I find it, I do not know how to change it.

After installing NVIDIA driver, it also installs a GUI based config tool where I can change display settings. It looks like this.

[image: NVIDIA config tool GUI]

It has "1366x768 (scaled)" but if I choose that "1366x768 (scaled)", the picture looks blur (i.e., not as it was when using my custom 1366x768 mode with opensource video driver), and also the taskbar (bottom panel) is gone.

I also tried to set LCD TV to 1360x768 or 1280x768 and use the LCD TV as primary, but if I do that, the taskbar (bottom panel) is gone.

Now I am stuck with laptop builtin display at 1366x768 but LCD TV at 1360x768, and LCD TV is missing the thin slice of 6 px at right hand side of the X screen.

### Additional system info

```
Linux version 6.0.0-6mx-amd64 (stevep@mxlinux.org) (gcc-10 (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Debian) 2.35.2) #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.0.12-1~mx21+1 (2022-12-15)
```

```
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
Release:    11
Codename:   bullseye
```

MX Linux 21 with KDE desktop.

Comment: Update: Nobody answers or even comments on this question... Maybe it is too specific to my intended usecase. I decided to ignore this for now, and config my laptop to only use the TV instead, when connected to TV. However, I am still only able to use it at 1360x768 instead of 1366x768.